# PHP PDO when data for bound parameters are not set

Tags: php, pdo

I get data from a querystring like below, where all 3 `country, state and sub` may not be set.

**Sometimes it may be**

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US&state=california&sub=sanjose`

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US&state=california`

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US`

Then I do:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select username from arraytest where country = :country and state = :state and sub = :sub');
    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $_GET['country']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_GET['state']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sub', $_GET['sub'])
    $stmt->execute();

    while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $rows['username'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

This'll work only if all the three are bound. If any one isn't received, no results are returned.

Is it possible to get it to work even if all the three where not bound?

**Example**

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US` would display results for

`select username from arraytest where country = US`

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US&state=california` would display results for

`select username from arraytest where country = US and state = california`

`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US&state=california&sub=sanjose` would display results for

`select username from arraytest where country = US and state=california and sub=sanjose`

Comment: ...and if none is set? All data?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Default is `US`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it;

```
$sql = 'select username from arraytest where country = :country';

if(isset($_GET['state')) {
  $sql .= ' and state = :state';

if(isset($_GET['sub')) {
  $sql .= ' and sub = :sub';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':country', isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : 'US');

if(isset($_GET['state')) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_GET['state']);

if(isset($_GET['sub')) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':sub', $_GET['sub']);
```

EDIT: If it's used in many places, you may want to make a simple function, something like;

```
function buildstmt($conn, $base, $params, $arr) {
  $prefix = ' WHERE ';
  foreach($params as $param=>$value) {
    if(isset($arr[$param])) $value = $arr[$param];
    if($value != null) {
      $base .= $prefix.$param.'=:'.$param;
      $prefix = ' AND ';
    }
  }
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  foreach($params as $param=>$value) {
    if(isset($arr[$param])) $value = $arr[$param];
    if($value != null)
      $stmt->bindParam(':'.$param, $value);
  }
  return $stmt;
}
```

Then you can call it as;

```
$stmt = buildstmt($conn, 'select username from arraytest',
                  array('country'=>'US', 'state'=>null, 'sub'=>null), $_GET);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: While this solution works, it's not very flexible. He may want to construct a method or a function that would be able to do that dynamically.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Added a function option.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare `sql` with condition

```
$sql = 'SELECT `username` FROM `arraytest` WHERE 1';

if(!empty($_GET['country'])) {
  $sql .= ' AND country = :country ';
}
if(!empty($_GET['state'])) {
  $sql .= ' AND state = :state ';
}
if(!empty($_GET['sub'])) {
  $sql .= ' AND sub = :sub ';
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

And `bindParam` like this :

```
if(!empty($_GET['country'])) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':country', $_GET['country']);
}
if(!empty($_GET['state'])) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_GET['state']);
}
if(!empty($_GET['sub'])) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':sub', $_GET['sub']);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Norman It means the query is dynamically constructed and putting in WHERE 1 leads to simpler logic for dynamic conditional clauses.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this:

```
$sql = 'select userName from arraytest where ';

if(!empty($_GET['country'])){ 
    echo 'Country Set <br>';
    $sql .= 'country = :country';
    $exe[':country'] = $_GET['country'];
} else { echo 'Country not set';}

if(!empty($_GET['state'])){ 
    echo 'State Set <br>';
    $sql .= ' and state = :state';
    $exe[':state'] = $_GET['state'];
} else { echo 'State not set';}

if(!empty($_GET['sub'])){ 
    echo 'Sub Set <br>';
    $sql .= ' and sub = :sub';
    $exe[':sub'] = $_GET['sub'];
}else{ echo 'Sub not set';}

print_r($exe);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute($exe);

while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $rows['userName'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```